# How to make bot not stop after error? Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have script which have to kick user with reason.

*Syntax:*

$kick @user Reason

but when I type:

$kick sometext nexttext

**I got error in console:**

TypeError: Cannot read property 'kick' of undefined

and bot stop...

How can I edit this script so that after entering an incorrect value, an error will not pop up turning off the bot and bot will send message to channel eg. "Incorrect value"?

**Script:**

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client;
const prefix = "$";
 client.on('message', function(message) {
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if(command === "kick") {

 let member = message.mentions.members.first();
 let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
  member.kick(reason);
  message.delete();
  client.channels.cache.get('737341022782357566').send("User <@" + member.id + "> with id " + member.id + " has been kicked by <@" + message.author.id + "> with reason " + reason)  

}})
client.login('token');
```

Answer (score 1):

in javascript to execute a code that have chances to chrash, you can use the statment

```
try {
//code to test
} catch(err) {
//code if it crash
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a `if (member)` to test if there was a mention.

In the else, you can send your "bad command" message

you should also only trigger the bot if the message starts with your prefix

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client;
const prefix = "$";

client.on('message', function(message) {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) { return } 
  //this line prevents the bot to execute every message
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if(command === "kick") {

    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    if (member) { // add this
      member.kick(reason);
      client.channels.cache.get('737341022782357566').send(`User ${member.user} with id: ${member.id} has been kicked by ${message.author} with reason: ${reason}`); 
    } else {
      message.reply("invalid parameters for $kick")
    }

    message.delete();
  }
})

client.login('token');
```

Comment: I got error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.



22 line

Comment: Okay i find solution